# Async task slowing down code (hashing)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, hash

I am writing a windows forms app that performs hashes on a list of words. To ensure that the app doesn't freeze while the hashing is in progress I am using an async task to perform the hashing. However, doing so causes the speed at which the hashes are processed to drop from multiple thousands per second to around 60 per second.

My hashing function is like this

```
private static string MD5Hash(string word)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var bytes = MD5.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(word));

    foreach (var value in bytes)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(value.ToString("X2"));
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

I implement the hashing function to hash words from a file like this (this is without using async which achieves a few thousand hashes per second)

```
private static void DoHashes()
{
    foreach (var word in File.ReadLines("the file path"))
    { 
        File.AppendAllText("the output path",  MD5Hash(word) + Environment.NewLine);         
    }   
}
```

I have then used an async task to avoid freezing my windows forms app like this (this results in the speed of the hashes to drop to around 60 per second)

```
private static async void DoHashes()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {       
        foreach (var word in File.ReadLines("the file path"))
        { 
            File.AppendAllText("the output path",  MD5Hash(word) + Environment.NewLine);      
        }  
    });
}
```

How can I avoid this speed decrease without causing my windows form to freeze whilst carrying out the hashes?

Comment: Do you call `DoHashes()` only once?

Comment: For debugging purposes, make a static int variable somewhere in your code, and increase it everytime DoHashes() gets called, so you can keep track of how many times it gets invoked and avoid unnecessary calls.

Comment: Try to make 2 different tests. 1: only counting MD5hash, 2: appending and counting hash. This will give you a hint to ques if it is file or CPU related.

Comment: Instead of calling `File.AppendAllText` in `foreach` loop, you should append the text to `StringBuilder` and at the last, you should write it to File from StringBuilder. This will definitely improve your performance as now application will not acquire file handle multiple times.

Comment: Please include your testing code.

Comment: DoHashes() only gets called once. If you read the code DoHashes() loops through each word in the passed in the word list and calls MD5Hash with the word as an argument. I appreciate the advice on changing the way the hashes are written to the file however that is also not the problem as without the async Task there is a dramatic increase in speed.

Comment: Regarding unit tests I cannot provide them for this exact code at the moment as this is a very small part of my actual code. If I get time tomorrow (and there is still no answer) I will write some test code for this and provide it in the post.

Comment: You need to show how exactly you measure that dramatic decrease in speed. Is that simple stopwatch inside DoHashes or something more complicated?

Comment: I have a function that calculates the hashes per second however you could easily see the difference if you ran each function for say 10  seconds (through a simple stopwatch) and counted the number of hashes in each respective file

Comment: @LostBoy Wrapping in a Task shouldn't cause such a decrease in perf. Are you running in debug or release? Is Garbage collection kicking in? You should refactor to user1672994's suggestion

Comment: I think, answer by user @user1672994 is correct. When you do `await`, once task is completed it will try to restore execution flow on _UI_ thread. App will wait until your UI thread will be available to continue execution. So, while hashing may take the same time, you may loose some time on waiting SyncContext restoration. `ConfigureAwait(false)` may help - it will not capture original context, however be sure you do not have any code after `DoHashes()` which will require UI thread (like updating TxtBox, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this test using a WPF application. At my test environment, I've used a File which has 5000 lines. Below are the responses

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|#        Description                                            Time Taken (in secs)
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1    Without Async/Await (As mentioned in the question)            144.933
|2    With Async/Await (As mentioned in the question)               145.563
|3    Using StringBuilder and writing to file only once             0.143
|4    With Async/Await and set ConfigureAwait to false              90.657
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you see the result, there is no major difference between Test#1 and Test#2 so wrapping to async-await should not make a difference in your scenario.

Below is the code for Test#3 and #4

**Test 3 (Using StringBuilder and writing to file only once )**

```
private static async void DoHashes()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in File.ReadLines(Input file path))
        {
           sb.AppendLine(MD5Hash(word));
        }

       File.AppendAllText(Output file path, sb.ToString());
    });

    sw.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show("Time Taken by Do Hashes : " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0) + " secs");
}
```

The result of this test is **0.143** (1000 times better than Test#1 and #2) as file handle is not being acquired by process multiple times.

**Test 4 (With Async/Await and set ConfigureAwait to false)**

```
private static async void DoHashes()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var word in File.ReadLines(Input file path)
        {
           File.AppendAllText(Output file path, MD5Hash(word) + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    sw.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show("Time Taken by Do Hashes : " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0) + " secs");
}
```

Setting the `ConfigureAwait` attempts to **NOT** to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured so you can see that performance has increased --- Compare to Test#1 and Test#2 it takes **40%** less time (takes only 90.657 secs).

Comment: Hmm thanks for the conclusion I’ll have to do more testing into why there is a speed decrease. Atleast I know it isn’t the task causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say you've done there is very little slow down at all.

Take this base case:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var results = source.Select(x => MD5Hash(x)).ToArray();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

This code completes in `5316.8091` milliseconds. That's 188 hashes per millisecond.

If I put my test in an `async` method and run this:

```
var results = await Task.Run(() => source.Select(x => MD5Hash(x)).ToArray());
```

...it then takes `5531.4172` milliseconds or about 181 hashes per millisecond.

And without the `async` I run this:

```
var results = Task.Run(() => source.Select(x => MD5Hash(x)).ToArray()).Result;
```

And it completes in `5441.0798` milliseconds or about 184 hashes per millisecond.

**So I can only conclude that the code you've presented isn't causing the slow down.**

---

Now, if you want to try and get this to work any faster try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. You can then write this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 1000000)
    from h in Observable.Start(() => MD5Hash(n.ToString()))
    select new { n, h };

query
    .ToArray()
    .Subscribe(xs =>
    {
        var results = xs.OrderBy(x => x.n).Select(x => x.h).ToArray();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    });
```

That runs on multiple background threads, but can marshal back to the UI and runs in sub-5 seconds.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq` to your code.

Answer (score -2):

When you don't need any Form interaction during/after the hashing then don't use async. The Task is enough.

```
private static void DoHashes()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {       
        foreach (var word in File.ReadLines("the file path"))
        { 
            File.AppendAllText("the output path",  MD5Hash(word) + Environment.NewLine);      
        }  
    });
}
```

Also, lay of the `static`s

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm asking. I need the async function as I need the form to still be responsive and regardless of that, the Task is what is causing the speed decrease.

Comment: No, Task.Run is what makes it go parallel. Async/await can be used to hook up your GUI.

Comment: @bommelding Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: note that `static` has its uses - it's not for naught that you use it.